# .htaccess to change URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

So i have a mvc system setup but it does not generate search engine friendly urls.

A typical url is in the format:

`http://sitedomain.com/class/classMethod?parameter=valueA?parameter2=valueB`

This is what i need to have:

`http://sitedomain.com/class/valueA/valueB/`

My .htaccess actually modified a part of the url already but i dont know how to do the second part

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1 [L,QSA]
```

(originally looked like `http://site.com/index.php?controller=class`, but after the htaccess below is ran, it looks like `http://site.com/class`)

If anyone could help me with this, that would be great, thank you.

Comment: Seems to me like you're going to not going to have the `classMethod`, `parameter` and `parameter2` being handed to the MVC after your rewrite as you've described it at the moment. This can't be what you want, surely? Perhaps there's a specific method and parameter names that you want to be handed for `/class/valueA/valueB`?

Comment: Actually the parameters are embedded in links so like (<a href="http://site.com/class/method?param=something"), when i click on the link i see exactly that in the url but all i really want is (http://site.com/className/classMethod/something)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following  .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$            rewrite.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

And extracting parts from the url is all done in PHP.
Parsing the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` variable.

(I find php code much easer to debug than complex apache rewrite rules.)

Comment: i actually dont know how to write .htaccess thats my problem, i cannot tamper with the php because its a view controller system so it maps the url to class and then to method of that class. So everything comes from the urls, my problem is that if i have parameters like /class/method?param=1&param2=3, and there could be any number of parameters including no parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/class/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?controller=class&parameter=$1&parameter2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: hmm but u see, i may or may not have parameters passed in, also there could be more than 2 parameters (not a defined number of them, since there will be different forms on the site). I think this is REALLY close to what i need.

Comment: Then add conditions for all the combinations of parameters you expect. Given that you cannot use a script to do these checks you don't have a ton of options.