# Change URL name

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

How is it possible to change the url to the name you want? For instance like [this site](http://www.lottanieminen.com/graphic-design/ki-kinnunen-book/) I want to change my domain url from `ahardenjr.com/project.html` to just `ahardenjr.com/project`.

I thought it was the base tag, but when I add `<base href="http://www.ahardenjr/project"/>`, the CSS just break. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at [pretty urls](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/)

Comment: I'm assuming you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825989/htaccess-to-change-url

Comment: @nightcracker I don't see how PHP comes into this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do a basic `mod_rewrite`. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to create a subdirectory named "project" and then make "project.html" your index file. I believe that should do the trick.

Comment: why would you use `project.html` and not use `index.html` if it's in a directory?

Comment: That's what I meant. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my answer. Nerdysyntax could rename the page that is currently `project.html` as `index.html`.